# Change Android Progress Dialog background color

Tags: android, background-color, progressdialog

[image]

is there any way to change the black color of Progress Dialog background?

Answer (score 17):

You can change the theme of the ProgressDialog like this:

```
ProgressDialog dialog = new ProgressDialog(this, AlertDialog.THEME_HOLO_DARK);
dialog.setTitle("Title");
dialog.setMessage("Message");
dialog.show();
```

Comment: `AlertDialog.THEME_HOLO_DARK` is deprecated.

Answer (score 6):

For a loading dialog with white background

```
ProgressDialog progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(this, AlertDialog.THEME_HOLO_LIGHT);
progressDialog.setMessage("Loading");
progressDialog.show();
```

Comment: `AlertDialog.THEME_HOLO_LIGHT` is deprecated.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
 textview.setTextColor(Color.RED); 
//textview must be defined in your class
```

or

```
root.setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE);
```

Comment: progressDialog.setMessage("Loading..");    progressDialog.show();

Answer (score -5):

Dialog.setBackgroundColor(name of color or hex value);

Comment: Sorry you will have to create custom progress dialog in order to change the background as Google one doesnt allow to change the background :)